# C++ program won't run on other commputers

Tags: visual-c++

I've been making c++ programs for fun and I've run into a dilemma. I made a program that literally just says "Hello World" and it only works on my friends computers. When ever it runs on my friends computers a message pops up saying "The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140D.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem." and then another message saying "The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140D.dll.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.". How can I fix this problem. I'm using Visual Studio Code to compile my programs. How can I make something that will work on other people's computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You need Visual C++ Redistributable Packages (available here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) to be able to run your program on another computer (if it doesn't have that already).
2. You can't distribute Debug packages, so you need to build the Release version of your program. (`D` in `MSVCP140D.dll` stands for `Debug`)